# Custom QCompleter with Two LineEdits in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement some sort of a custom qcompleter with specific completion rules. Basically, for an entry in my list that is multiple words, I want it to give suggestions based on the prefix for all of the words, not just the first one. Then when the user fills in the first lineEdit with the suggestion I want it to put the first word in the first lineEdit, then the rest of it in the second lineEdit.

For example, my list contains the entry "pizza chikin chikin." When the user types in either 'ch' or 'pi' into the first lineEdit, the entire string "pizza chikin chikin" should still be suggested. When the user selects "pizza chikin chikin" the word "pizza" should show up in the first lineEdit then "chikin chikin" will show up in the other.

As of now, my completer only suggests strings that have the prefix of the user text. So if I type in 'ch' only strings that start with "ch" will be suggested, so "pizza chikin chikin" will not be suggested. But once I type in 'pi' then it will be suggested

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(439, 254)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 90, 180, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")


        food = ["pizza chikin", "chikin pizza", "chikin pizza pizza", "chikin, pizza", "fried pizza"]

        completer = QCompleter(food)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter-Mode-property

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop

is what you are looking for. Set it to `Qt.MatchContains`

Comment: This worked, thanks! But I still need to find a way to fill in the text for the second line edit when a suggested text is selected for the first one. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So if the user selects "chikin pizza" 'chikin' will be put into the first lineEdit and 'pizza will be put into the other'